# CORS policy and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I can register, update and delete everything. However, when I will
request security, I'm blocked by CORS.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

My cors config class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfiguration(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }
        };
    }
```

In SecurityConfig.class:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //resguarda aplicações web dentro do projeto
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            //aplicação não guardará sessões (será pelo token)
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

authService.ts:

```
tentarLogar(username: string, password: string): Observable<any>{
    const params = new HttpParams()
                        .set('username', username)
                        .set('password', password)
                        .set('grant_type', 'password')
    
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${this.clientID}:${this.clientSecret}`),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    return this.http.post(this.tokenURL, params.toString, {headers})
  }
```

If needs more some code please tell me.
But as I said, with this configuration I can access the API, the real problem is not being able to access `localhost:8080/oauth/token` to get the JWT token.

**EDIT:**

new CorsConfiguration.class:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class WebConfig implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Authorization, Content-Type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you have a custom cors filter, it is not needed, spring security has a cors filter.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using Spring Security's Legacy OAuth 2.0 support (`org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2`). If that's the case, then you have two options:

#### Use the newer support

If your application is new enough, you may prefer to switch to Spring Security 5's built-in support. Spring Security has [a sample for minting self-signed JWTs based on HTTP Basic authentication](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login), that may be useful.

In that case, the `/token` endpoint is configured using the same `HttpSecurity` as the rest of your endpoints, meaning you only configure CORS in one place, as you have already done.

#### Configure in `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`

In the legacy support, the OAuth endpoints are added in a separate Spring Security filter chain. As such, you need to configure that filter chain for CORS as well.

If you need to stick with the legacy support, then to configure the authorization server endpoints, like `/oauth/token`, you need to [use the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1512#issuecomment-478758610) like so:

```java
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class MyAuthorizationServerConfiguration 
        extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer server) {
       // other configs

       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
       CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
       config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/token", config);
       CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter(source);
       security.addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(filter);
   }
}
```

Comment: I was stucked with this problem for a couple of days and this solved it. Thx!